# How to specify the user while running a Jenkins job in a slave node in Linux

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins master slave configuration in a Centos machine. Previous all the Jenkins jobs were run as the root user in my slave node. Now I see that the jobs are run as another user.

I was trying to figure out the configuration where I can specify the user for a job in the Jenkins slave configuration or in job level.

My job includes code checkouts and folder creations. Since the job is supposed to be executed as different user, I am facing a lot of permission issues. Is there any way to specify the linux user for a jenkins job or node?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to configure whole slave to work as specific user (in node configuration: *Nodes -> [your node] -> Configure -> Launch method -> Credentials*) and grant all needed permissions to that user.

If it's not an option you may use `sudo` to run certain commands as a specific user. Passwords may be stored safely in Jenkins *Credentials* and [injected](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/203802500-Injecting-Secrets-into-Jenkins-Build-Jobs) as environmental variables in job. Then script may look like that (`sudopass` is injected secret):

```
echo $sudopass | sudo -S -u your_user your_command
```